# Finding reason for the inaccurate results, copying code from research paper

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing

I am trying to replicate the linear programming solver that this person has made

http://www.idi.ntnu.no/~elster/master-studs/spampinato/spampinato-linear-prog-gpu-report.pdf.

The device I am using is Quadro FX 1800M with compute capability 1.2.

My problem is that when I launch more than 22 threads per block then most of the time I get inaccurate results (sometimes all zeros), however in unique cases I get accurate results when I launch even 512 threads per block.

Here are some test runs that I made. (Sequential Implies a CPU based Version) used for comparison

```
Iteration No 1 : of Sequential Version
Optimum Found 24.915583
Elapsed time: 0.001049725

Iteration No 1: of Parallel Version
BS-(Number of Threads) = : 20
Optimum found: 24.915583

Iteration No 2: of Parallel Version
BS-(Number of Threads) = : 256
Optimum found: 24.915607

Iteration No 3: of Parallel Version
BS-(Number of Threads) = : 512
Optimum found: 24.917068

Iteration No 4: of Parallel Version
BS-(Number of Threads) = : 2
Optimum found: 24.915583

Iteration No 5: of Parallel Version
BS-(Number of Threads) = : 456 
Optimum found: -30693000299230806209574138333792043008.000000

Iteration No 6: of Parallel Version
BS-(Number of Threads) = : 456
Problem unsolvable: either qth==0 or loop too long.

Iteration No 7: of Parallel Version
BS-(Number of Threads) = : 512
Optimum found: 25.010513

Iteration No 8: of Parallel Version
BS-(Number of Threads) = : 256
Problem unsolvable: either qth==0 or loop too long.

Iteration No 9: of Parallel Version
BS-(Number of Threads) = : 256
Optimum found: 0.000000

Iteration No 10: of Parallel Version
BS-(Number of Threads) = : 512
Optimum found: 0.000000
```

Can somebody kindly point what I might be doing wrong, I know that I haven't posted the code but I am assuming that the code is correct as I am copying it from the research paper and the problem is on my end.

I should also point out that I am getting the following error when compiling the cuda code

*ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_000017e7_00000000-10_culiblp.ptx, line 263; warning :       Double is not supported. Demoting to float*

Might this be a reason for the results?

Comment: Please check all API calls for errors: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is that when I launch more than 22 threads per block then most of the time I get inaccurate results(sometimes all zeros),
>
> Can somebody kindly point what I might be doing wrong,

I wasn't able to build the code because the header files seem to be missing from the paper.  I could try and construct those, but one thing I noticed is that the variable (or constant) `BS` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.  So I'm guessing it was originally defined in `culiblp.h` (which is not provided.)

Looking at `culiblp.cu` in the paper, I notice some kernel launches like this:

```
init_AInD<<<dim3(kn, km1), dim3(BS, BS)>>>(devA, devD, m, n);
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is creating a 2D threadblock of dimensions `BS`*`BS`.  So if you set `BS` to a value greater than 22, the product will exceed 512 threads, which is the maximum for your cc1.x GPU.  In that case, setting BS to a value higher than 22 will cause that kernel launch to fail.

I believe this is certainly a contributing factor to code failure when `BS` is larger than 22.

You could prove this out by running your code with `cuda-memcheck`.  Also, if you plan to work with this code, I'd suggest adding [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589).

The apparent, occasional successes with values higher than 22 for `BS` could possibly be explained if you had done a successful run (let's say with `BS` at 22 or less) immediately prior.  It's possible that even with a failed kernel, if the previous successful intermediate data is left in memory from the previous run, that things will seem to produce the correct results.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer, I overlooked this
   init_AInD<<<dim3(kn, km1), dim3(BS, BS)>>>(devA, devD, m, n);